# Terminology: Is "CL" identical to "the MSVC compiler"

Tags: visual-c++, cl

I am having a hard time to make out whether the command line tool `cl.exe` is what people refer to when they are talking about "the MSVC compiler".

Are the two the same thing or do you use cl to control the compiler?

Comment: Sounds to me like a distinction without a difference. You type `cl mysource.cpp` on the command line - does it really matter whether `cl` is doing all the work, or delegates some or all of it to other binaries? Anyway, there are, in fact, a bunch of DLLs and EXEs involved.

Comment: The point is that I don't know whether cl IS MSCV or not. In other words is there something like an MSVC executable (that I can't find on my system)? If so, how is it different from the cl executable?

Comment: Well, there's Visual Studio IDE, housed in `devenv.exe`. The command-line C++ compiler shipped with Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) product is indeed named `cl.exe` (at least, that's the entry point; it invokes a bunch of other tools).